# Import site specific data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For some time now I've been trying ways to successfully import specific data from the Site https://www.infogol.net/matches/result/english-premier-league/everton-vs-wolves-2019-09-01/30701

In the Stats tab, in Maps, there is the data called Infogol xG, that's exactly what I want to be able to play for my spreadsheet.

I tried with various formats of ImporXML and ImportDATA but never succeeded.

I would like your help in trying to find a form via script or even formulas to be able to capture this data, is of paramount importance to the study I am doing on the qualitative system of kicks in football games.

[image]

[Image Link specifying the data I need](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OckvnFVG25uTP7Otaj1FgRiGE8Zh_quN/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this answer? In this answer, `IMPORTXML` is used. Unfortunately, the values of `1.54, 2.14` cannot be directly retrieved from the HTML data of the URL. So the values are retrieved from a sentence. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample formula:

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[2]/p[1]/text()[last()]"),"\(\w.+\)|[^\d. ]","")," |. |.$","@"),"@",TRUE,TRUE)
```

In this case, `https://www.infogol.net/matches/result/english-premier-league/everton-vs-wolves-2019-09-01/30701` is put in the cell "A1". The flow of this formula is as follows.

1. Retrieve the HTML data from URL using the xpath of `//div[2]/p[1]/text()[last()]` with `IMPORTXML`.
2. Retrieve the value from the HTML data using `REGEXREPLACE`.
3. The values you want are retrieved using `REGEXREPLACE` and `SPLIT`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This formula can be used for the current URL of `https://www.infogol.net/matches/result/english-premier-league/everton-vs-wolves-2019-09-01/30701`. When you want to use this for other URL and/or the page design of URL is changed, an error might occur. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.